# Live meeting recordings get saved as separate Audio and Video files

Tags: video, audio, recording, live-meeting

I am trying to record a Live meeting session. It gets saved as separate Audio and Video files which makes it impossible to open them in Windows Media player.

But when I open the file from Live Meeting Recording Manager, it opens the video in Browser and works well.

So can some one advise me how to save both the audio/video in same file and also to merge the audio and video for existing saved sessions ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a *Live Meeting* license and I'm unfamiliar with it, but merging audio and video streams from separate files is trivial, if you have a bit of disk space available. I suggest you merge them in a matroska container, using [*mkvtoolnix*](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html), but there are many other container formats and software packages available for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Live Meeting Converter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/live-meeting-help/download-the-recording-converter-for-microsoft-office-live-meeting-2007-HA010355066.aspx) tool, it takes all those files and combines them.

Comment: link no longer works...

Comment: link appears to be working